# How to get variable value from ajax serialized data in laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, laravel-5

I have a form with change function

```
$('#filters').change(function(){
    fdata = $('#filters').serialize();
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/find/family/filters",
        data: { _token: CSRF_TOKEN, data: fdata },
        datatype: "json",
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data.city);
});
```

Serialized data:

```
_token=JnIowhkyoJjfgB4iReqatXTezAGsrNXumpgN1B6h&area=1&type=&state=1&city=1
```

And the controller here

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('city');
    return response(['city' => $data]);
}
```

The console data is

```
object {city:null}
```

How can I get variables' values?

Comment: log fdata before sending the Ajax and see what's its value ?

Comment: It is same as I mentioned at serialized data. @Matt.k

Comment: try `fdata  = $("#yourFormID :input").serialize()`  .Don't forget to give each input a name